# How do I get column information about a table in an attached db?

Tags: sqlite

I have two databases attached into one connection. They both have a table of the same name, but they have different structure. I want to get the column information for one of them.

I tried: `PRAGMA table_info(database-name.table-name);` but I get `syntax error near '.'`. Any idea on how to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `select * from database-name.sqlite_master where name='table'`?

Comment: @JackManey I could get the create string with that, but then I would have to parse it myself

Comment: Looking through the documentation, that seems to be the only way to do it (that I can find, anyway).